# Return the first occurrence using Regex

Tags: regex

I have the following expression:

[Document[_id=5f9ecf8ca9bec5549493ba7d,·policy_name=xxx,·is_mobile=false, Document[_id=6090fead53bc363849fce989,·policy_name=yyy,·is_mobile=true, Document[_id=619cf036761c281e3ad12327,·policy_name=zzz,·is_mobile=false, Document[_id=619cf729ea016d1e3336e903,·policy_name=xyz,·is_mobile=false]

I would like to capture ONLY the first Document id (i.e- 5f9ecf8ca9bec5549493ba7d).
i tried this regex- `(?<=Document\[_id=).*?[^,]*` BUT it will return all the Document id's.

1).how can i capture the first / second (Nth match) of document id from the expression?

2). is it possible to do regex AND operator to find the Document id with "is_mobile=true"?
(i.e 5f9ecf8ca9bec5549493ba7d & true)

would really appreciate any help

EDIT:
i'm using https://regex101.com/

this is the link in which i tried to capture the first / second (nth occurance of Document id  ( i need only the number) - https://regex101.com/r/ZnYRhq/1

Comment: "BUT it will return all the Document id's" that probably depends on the implementation - what language/framework/application are you using to apply said regular expression with?

Comment: From regex tag info: “Because regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.” Instead of all these useless regex related tags, give the language/tool you are using.

Comment: Sorry for not adding the missing info. I added it in the description.

Comment: Regex101 gives choice to multiple languages, which one are you using? It will be better to give a link to your attempts.

Comment: this is the link in which i tried to capture the first / second (nth occurance of Document id  ( i need only the number) - https://regex101.com/r/ZnYRhq/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not language listed, but one approach could be using a capture group for the value that you want, and start the pattern with an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string.

For the first Document id:

```
^.*?\bDocument\[_id=([^\]\[\s,]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D92blZ/1)

For the first Document id that has `is_mobile=true` (assuming that the order of the  key-value pairs is as given in the example and is within the same opening and closing square brackets)

```
^.*?\bDocument\[_id=([^\]\[\s,]+),[^\]\[]*\bis_mobile=true\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?\bDocument\[_id=` Match the first occurrence of `Document[_id=`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\]\[\s,]+` Match 1+ times any char except `]` `[` whitespace char or `,`
- `)` Close group 1
- `,[^\]\[]*` Match a comma and optional chars other than `]` and `[`
- `\bis_mobile=true\b` Match `is_mobile=true` between word boundaries

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DCXnV7/1)

Or using lookarounds for a single (not global) match:

```
(?<=Document\[_id=)[^,]*(?=,[^][]*\bis_mobile=true\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aEvg1y/1)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but can you tell me (give an example) how i can capture the first / second match of the Document id ( Only the number , i.e: 5f9ecf8ca9bec5549493ba7d ). from your example it capture also the Document_id text. regarding the second section, i would like to capture only the document id ( the number and the is mobile=true. can it be done using regex? this is the regex i tried and expression- https://regex101.com/r/ZnYRhq/1

Comment: @geoedge What is the tool or language?

Comment: @geoedge Do you mean like this? `(?<=Document\[_id=)[^,]*(?=,[^][]*\bis_mobile=true\b)` See https://regex101.com/r/aEvg1y/1

Comment: Thanks, that solved me the second section. can you tell me how i can catch the first / second (nth occurance) for Document_id (only the numbers) ?

Comment: @geoedge The first pattern you can simplify to `(?<=Document\[_id=)[^,\s]+` https://regex101.com/r/UbQQdU/1

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?
`(?:^\[Document\[_id=)([^,]+)` for the first?

For n-th you need to use capturing group but how to do this is language/framework dependent.

Comment: I tried it using  https://regex101.com/ but i got errors- (? Incomplete group structure
) Incomplete group structure

Comment: Pardon, missed the ":" after "?". Try now.

Answer (score 0):

```
txt="""
[Document[_id=5f9ecf8ca9bec5549493ba7d,·policy_name=xxx,·is_mobile=false, Document[_id=6090fead53bc363849fce989,·policy_name=yyy,·is_mobile=true, Document[_id=619cf036761c281e3ad12327,·policy_name=zzz,·is_mobile=false, Document[_id=619cf729ea016d1e3336e903,·policy_name=xyz,·is_mobile=false]
"""

print([i.split('=')[1].strip(' ') for i in txt.split(',') if '_id' in i ][0])
```

output:

```
 5f9ecf8ca9bec5549493ba7d
```